# Delete sheet in excel that I can't access

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete a sheet that for some reason I cannot access. It crashes Excel every time I want to access it. I'm using the following macro to delete sheets that are unwanted on closing (all sheets that starts with "SHEET") are being deleted on closing. So I thought I could use the same macro and change "SHEET" to "CHART" but for some reason the macro does not recognize that I have sheet called "CHART1" in the workbook, so that unwanted sheet stays there. Since it make the workbook crashes every time

Is there a way I can remove this sheet, another macro maybe?

Here's the macro I'm currently using to delete the CHART sheets:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim flg As Boolean    

For Each sh In Worksheets
     If sh.Name Like "Chart*" Then flg = True: Exit For
Next
If flg = True Then
     Call Delete_NEW_Unwanted_CHART
End If        

If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
     ThisWorkbook.Save
End If

End sub
```

In a Module I have :

```
Sub Delete_NEW_Unwanted_CHART()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Charts
    If Left(ws.Name, 5) = "Chart" Then                
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If        
Next ws

End Sub
```

When I run this with breakpoint, it doesn't even recognize that I have a sheet named "CHART1". It is as if the flag for this Chart sheet is never recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `ws` as a worksheet and then looped it through an array of charts (effectively for for each worksheet in the charts with the workbook - which doesn't make sense) try `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets` arguement and `Next`

Answer (score 0):

I actually just found what was wrong with it. 
Here's the proper macros if anyone has that problem in the future:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
For Each shC In Charts
 If shC.Name Like "Chart*" Then flg = True: Exit For
        Next
         If flg = True Then
    Call Delete_NEW_Unwanted_CHART
         End If


If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
End If
End sub
```

In module write:

```
Sub Delete_NEW_Unwanted_CHART()
Dim wsC As Chart

For Each wsC In ThisWorkbook.Charts
 If Left(wsC.Name, 5) = "Chart" Then

          Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wsC.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If

     Next wsC


 End Sub
```

Have a nice day everyone :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

Dim sh As Chart
Dim flg As Boolean

For Each sh In Charts
    If Left(sh.Name, 5) = "Chart" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        sh.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next

If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Good point @SJR!! I was making my life way to complicated :-)

Comment: Or just `If sh.Name Like "Chart*" Then`. You can remove your `Dim flg As Boolean` as you are not using it anywhere in your code